# MongoDb schema strucrure

Tags: mongodb

I am new to stack overflow, I don't have that much idea how to write question, please consider.

I have requirement.

I have to store Post and its comments in MongoDb for that I create following Json format.

```
{"POST_TITLE":"Title",
"POST_DESCRIPTION":"Description",
"COMMENTS":[
            {COMMENT1},
            {COMMENT2} 
           ] 
}
```

Please tell me is it good structure or any additional thing I have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks good already.

Comment: Ok, Is number of comments affect on it ?.